# How to display a visual marker on the last overlay

Tags: beamer, overlays

Is it possible to display a visual "marker" on the last overlay of every frame? I want to know when an overlay "ends" before I go to the next frame.

Comment: Welcome to Texas. Please provide a minimal answer.

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: Welcome to texsx. Please provide a minimal example/solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you could end each frame with

```
\only<.>{STOP here}
```

or some other marker as in the following where the `.` denotes the current value of the overlay counter at the end of the frame.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<+-> one
    \item<+-> two 
    \item<+-> three
  \end{itemize}

\only<.>{STOP here}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<+-> one one
    \item<+-> two two
    \item<+-> three three
  \end{itemize}

\only<.>{STOP here}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great. Is there a way to put this on every frame automatically?

Comment: you can probably go in the preamble `\let\oldendframe\endframe \def\endframe{\only<.>{.....}\oldendframe`

Comment: This seems to work only if you use the <+-> overlay specification. Not if you use <1-> and so on... (beamer v3.66) :-(